# Is there any way i can keep my tiny tower progress?

Tags: tiny-tower

I've read several other questions and answers like this, and most of them say it's connected to your facebook account or something like that.. but my device is not connected to the internet and never has been. So is there anyway when i can transfer my tiny tower progress on to my new device? (which won't be connected to the internet either?) thank you

Comment: Can you expand on your devices model/make

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is possible as since your devices aren't connected to the internet, there isn't a way to transfer data to your new device. So unless both of your devices are connected to the internet, transferring towers is not possible.

Comment: This deserves the check. Good answer Dakarath.

Comment: I think that the author is inactive.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, IFF you can get internet on both devices. Sign in to Game Center on the "original phone". At some points within the game, it will be saved. In your "new" phone, install Tiny Tower, run it, and when prompted, login to Game Center. It should ask if you want to Restore from the saved game.

[Read More](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Is_there_any_way_you_can_transfer_your_old_tiny_tower_to_your_new_iPhone#ixzz2rIWeYVtn)

Comment: The asker is asking if they could transfer saves WITHOUT internet. Signing in to game center requires internet.

Comment: Correct @Scribblenautical. Hence the use of IFF (if and only iff), so rather than providing a simple "no you cant, because..." I have supplied "Yes, but you will need...". So rather than confirming with the user what they already know, i've provided a solution albeit not exactly helpful for the user, but hypothetically if they get internet access then it would be a solution.